# Connecting flight, do I have to exit and go security again?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, short-connections, connecting-flights, domestic-travel

My daughter and I will be flying (short domestic trip) from Philly to Orlando. She just wanted to ride the airplane and found a very cheap fare roundtrip.

If the connecting flight is to go back to Philly from Orlando, do we have to exit again since its only a 30 mins gap or we could just wait for the plane in the waiting area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If it's a domestic round trip, you don't need to leave the secure area, provided both flights arrive/depart from the same terminal and you have already checked in for both flights (most conveniently done online). You just need to get off, walk over to your next gate and hop on again.

> If the connecting flight is to go back to philly from orlando, do we
>   have to exit again since its only a 30 mins gap or we cld just wait
>   for the plane in the waiting area.

You are not going to wait, you will probably run like heck. 30 minutes is awfully tight. You still need to get out of the plane, and walk to your next gate which may be far away. Most carriers close the gate 15 minutes before departure, if you arrive at your gate later than this, you won't be able to get on. Even if everything is on time, this will be difficult and if your incoming flight is only a little delayed, you will miss your return.

Keep in mind this is NOT a connection, it's a round trip. If you miss your return flight, the airline is in no way required to rebook or refund you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Hilmar. We are not bringing bags. My plan b is (if we miss it) to buy another ticket (next schedule) while in the waiting are since it’s only $58.

Comment: @Justin Kyuk It might be only $58 at the moment but that doesn’t necessarily mean it would be the same price on the day

Comment: @JustinKyuk beware that fares bought on the same day may be quite different from fares bought in advance, especially at busy times. There’s also the risk there would be no availabilities on the day (or even for a few days, in some cases). On the other hand, it’s possible (though unlikely in this case IMHO) that it would actually be the same plane going back.

Comment: There are websites which will tell you which aircraft flew that route yesterday. [Instructions on our sister site](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16441/how-to-determine-the-aircraft-tail-number-on-a-particular-flight). From this you should be able to figure out if you will be on the same plane at the same gate, or have to run like crazy.

Comment: Even if the flight is on the same plane, you will have to deplane, and then turn around and present your boarding pass for the second flight before being allowed to re-board.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are familiar with the Orlando airport and terminals are separated by security? They aren't always (I don't know Orlando and didn't check).

Comment: Given the lack of time, you are very likely to miss the return flight. If taking a later flight only costs $58, it may be better to do that now, rather than risk not being able to get home for a day or so, or having to pay a very high fare for a same day booking.

Comment: Although the connection may not be officially protected, I feel that there's a very good chance you can get them to rebook you for free under the flat tire rule. I've gotten free rebookings for lateness that was undoubtedly my fault.